# How to group by in service now?

Tags: javascript, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, servicenow-hrsd

I am new in service now and I don't know yet how to manipulate the data unlike in MySQL and SQL. I just want to know how can I group by the data.

Here is my code to show the data:

```
var group = new GlideRecord("table");
    
group.addEncodedQuery('u_active=True');
group.orderBy('u_order_in_services');
group.query();
            
while (group.next()) {
gs.info(group.group_name);  

}
```

The result is:

```
Group 1
Group 1
Group 2 
Group 2
Group 3
Group 3
```

Needed result is:

```
Group 1
Group 2
Group 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GlideAggregate` (instead of of `GlideRecord`) if you need a GROUP BY.

There is an introduction here:

- https://developer.servicenow.com/blog.do?p=/post/glideaggregate/

Answer (score 0):

You could use GlideQuery for this, example:

```js
var group = new global.GlideQuery('sys_user_group')
    .where('active', true)
    .orderBy('name')
    .select('name')
    .toArray(100); 

GQ.jsonDebug(group)
```

[GlideQuery API Documentation](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/sandiego/server/no-namespace/GlideQueryAPI#GQ-orderBy_S?navFilter=glidequery)

Answer (score 0):

With either GlideQuery or GlideAggregate, to get the result you want you should use the `groupBy` method. It's hard to tell precisely what you're doing since you didn't give us the actual table name, but, following your example, the code should look like this:

```
new GlideQuery('table')
  .where('u_active', true)
  .groupBy('group_name')
  .aggregate('count')
  .select()
  .map(function (record) { return record.group.group_name })
  .forEach(GQ.debug);
```

A comparable GlideAggregate example would look like this:

```
var ga = GlideAggregate('table');
ga.addQuery('u_active', true);
ga.groupBy('group_name');
ga.addAggregate('COUNT')
ga.query();

while (ga.next()) {
  gs.debug(ga.getValue('group_name'));
}
```

Note, I removed the `orderBy` clause of both these queries since it makes less sense when we're grouping the results. Also, if this really is a custom table, I would triple-check that the `group_name` field isn't actually named `u_group_name`. If so, you'll need to update my examples to work properly.